# specifying a regression in R with an indicator variable

Tags: r, formula, regression

I would like to specify a regression in R that would estimate coefficients on `x` that are conditional on a third variable, `z`, being greater than 0.  For example

```
y ~ a + x*1(z>0) + x*1(z<=0)
```

What is the correct way to do this in R using formulas?

Comment: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/modules/dummy_vars.htm

Comment: @liuminzhao: I don't think this answers the question. Setting z up as a factor wouldn't allow you to do this kind of conditional regression.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Thanks, I misunderstood op's question. Maybe create 2 new covariates, like `x1 = x*I(z>0)` and `x2 = x*I(z<=0)` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The ":" (colon) operator is used to construct conditional interactions (when used with disjoint predictors constructed with `I`). Should be used with predict

```
> y=rnorm(10)
> x=rnorm(10)
> z=rnorm(10)
> mod <- lm(y ~ x:I(z>0) )
> mod

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x:I(z > 0))

Coefficients:
    (Intercept)  x:I(z > 0)FALSE   x:I(z > 0)TRUE  
      -0.009983        -0.203004        -0.655941  

> predict(mod, newdata=data.frame(x=1:10, z=c(-1, 1)) )
         1          2          3          4          5          6          7 
-0.2129879 -1.3218653 -0.6189968 -2.6337471 -1.0250057 -3.9456289 -1.4310147 
         8          9         10 
-5.2575108 -1.8370236 -6.5693926 
> plot(1:10, predict(mod, newdata=data.frame(x=1:10, z=c(-1)) )  )
> lines(1:10, predict(mod, newdata=data.frame(x=1:10, z=c(1)) ) )
```

Might help to look at its model matrix:

```
> model.matrix(mod)
   (Intercept) x:I(z > 0)FALSE x:I(z > 0)TRUE
1            1      -0.2866252     0.00000000
2            1       0.0000000    -0.03197743
3            1      -0.7427334     0.00000000
4            1       2.0852202     0.00000000
5            1       0.8548904     0.00000000
6            1       0.0000000     1.00044600
7            1       0.0000000    -1.18411791
8            1       0.0000000    -1.54110256
9            1       0.0000000    -0.21173300
10           1       0.0000000     0.17035257
attr(,"assign")
[1] 0 1 1
attr(,"contrasts")
attr(,"contrasts")$`I(z > 0)`
[1] "contr.treatment"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  y <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
  z <- sample(x=-10:10,size=length(trt),replace=T)
  x <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
  a <- rnorm(n=length(x))
  lm(y~a+I(x*1*I(z>0))+ I(x*1*I(z<=0)))
```

But I think using the `:` operator in DWIN solution is more elegant..

**Edit**

lm(y~a+I(x*1*I(z>0))+ I(x*1*I(z<=0)))

Call:

```
lm(formula = y ~ a + I(x * 1 * I(z > 0)) + I(x * 1 * I(z <= 0)))

Coefficients:
         (Intercept)                     a   I(x * 1 * I(z > 0))  I(x * 1 * I(z <= 0))  
              6.5775               -0.1345               -0.3352               -0.3366  

> lm(formula = y ~ a+ x:I(z > 0))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ a + x:I(z > 0))

Coefficients:
    (Intercept)                a  x:I(z > 0)FALSE   x:I(z > 0)TRUE  
         6.5775          -0.1345          -0.3366          -0.3352
```

Comment: I think `y ~ x*I(z>0)` might give what your construction produced, but I don't think it is what the OP was expecting. It gives an extra intercept term.

Comment: @DWin Right. I can simplify it to `lm(y~a+I(x*I(z>0))+ I(x*I(z<=0)))` but When I compare my solution with it gives the same result.

Comment: Both give an extraneous term but they are different coefficients. I'm not clear that either one can be called correct, Correctness would depend on predictions, but ease of understanding depends on whether the coefficients have a natural interpretation as slopes.